# Non-Unicode CSV Export from SQL Server Report Server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, csv, report

I am using the SQL Server Report Server from Microsoft SQL Server 2005.

In the report server report viewer control, there is a CSV download option.  The CSV download option is currently downloading a Unicode CSV file, which does not load into Microsoft Excel with the correct column formatting.

If I save the Unicode CSV file and convert it to a ASCII file it works fine in Excel.

How can I can I set a report or the SSRS Report Viewer to export CSV as ASCII instead of Unicode?

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Comment: I just ran into the same issue but there is also a Save As when you right click a Grid In SQL Server. I hope someone answers this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to the **RSReportserver.config** file (should be in the root of your reportserver virtual directory e.g. "**C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.3\Reporting Services\ReportServer**")

Find the CSV Extension - should look something like below. Change the Encoding node to read **ASCII** instead of **Unicode** or whatevr you have in there.

```
        <Extension Name="CSV" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.CsvRenderer.CsvReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.CsvRendering">
            <Configuration>
                <DeviceInfo>
                    <Encoding>Unicode</Encoding>
                </DeviceInfo>
            </Configuration>
        </Extension>
```

Comment: Locating config file:  (Note 1) Your subfolder under `Microsoft SQL Server` may begin with `MSRS`, like ours: `MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVERBO`.  (Note 2) You may have to actually ***NAVIGATE*** into the `Reporting Services` folder, at least once, before its config files will show up on file searches:  double-clicking folder `Reporting Services`, I got: "You don't currently have permission to access this folder.  Click Continue to permanently get access to this folder."  BEFORE clicking Continue, files under `Reporting Services` were NOT listed on file searches; AFTER Continue, searches found them!

Comment: Ahh the joys of MSRS, nice tips!

Comment: <Encoding>Unicode</Encoding> didn't work for me. But
<Encoding>UTF-8</Encoding> did. worth a read : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155365.aspx

Answer (score 2):

More information at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156281.aspx. You can create multiple extensions, i.e. in addition to the default "CSV" you can add "CSV - ASCII" or "CSV - Pipe" etc.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness here's how you go about adding a "CSV-ANSI" export option.You'll need to add an "OverrideNames" tag so that you don't get duplicate "CSV" options. As I'm in Australia I needed to add a "en-AU" language option, you can remove it if you don't need it (or replace with your own language).

```
<Extension Name="CSV-UTF8" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.DataRenderer.CsvReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataRendering">
    <OverrideNames>
        <Name Language="en-US">CSV (UTF8)</Name>
        <Name Language="en-AU">CSV (UTF8)</Name>
    </OverrideNames>                
</Extension>

<Extension Name="CSV-ANSI" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.DataRenderer.CsvReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataRendering">
    <OverrideNames>
        <Name Language="en-US">CSV (ANSI)</Name>
        <Name Language="en-AU">CSV (ANSI)</Name>
    </OverrideNames>                
    <Configuration>     
        <DeviceInfo>
            <Encoding>ASCII</Encoding>
        </DeviceInfo>
    </Configuration>
</Extension>
```

Comment: +1 Much better than overriding the CSV setting across your whole ssrs site!

Comment: Thanks @Davos, been using this solution for a while now and it's working well.

Answer (score 0):

In the save button there is small drop down menu which says "Save with encoding" where you can specify the encoding type as ansi
~Ram