# Formatting of exported SSRS report to CSV file

Tags: csv, reporting-services, export-to-csv

My 2008R2 SSRS report contains a detail column called debit which is formatted like "#,0.00".  When I export the file via .csv the debit column does not always have the right formatting of 0.00.  If the number is 0, then what appears is "0".  If the number is 123.40, then it appears as 123.4.  If the number is 123.44, then it appears as 1213.44.

I want each number in this column to always have 2 decimal places in the .csv file.  I checked out many other articles on stackoverflow about this, but none seem to address this issue correctly.

I tried changing the format to many other formats.  I noticed when I changed the format in SSRS to "C" for currency, then the 2 decimal places appeared.  But the problem with that is my users do not want the "$" symbol.

I tried changing the CSV export to ASCII format in the config file, but that did not work.
I used the code here:[Non-Unicode CSV Export from SQL Server Report Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691620/non-unicode-csv-export-from-sql-server-report-server)

Can anyone help me with getting the format correct in the CSV file without mannually changing the CSV file?

Thank you!

Comment: Just a guess really but did you try the format #,###.##?

Comment: Works for me in SSRS 2008 R2 - I get two decimal places always. You could try the format `N2` to see if that works.

Comment: Yes, I tried both, but neither of these work either.  Does anyone else have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem mentioned is report header's are being displayed when user generate report for CSV format, which is not supposed to be like that. But actually in CSV Format, While in the preview , we can hide or show **report header's** and it doesn't show **textbox names** .

```
  While in the exported/generated one , the CSV format hides the report's headers, but instead of that it shows textbox names and any changes We made in the properties to change that textbox name to make it as blank or disappear, it reflects on that column values but doesn't on that textbox name.
```

So I want to mention that better We can give some other meaningful names or by default it shows as 'Textbox1', but we must give any valid name to that textbox name and it appears on the generated CSV format.

**NOTE:** I also want to mention that all visibility properties works well with the report header's but not on the textbox names.